# axis.labelOverlap not working - what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to implement labelOverlap to hide every other x-axis label, but it is not working. I've seen other people define labelOverlap under 'layer', which I have tried but it also did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As you can see in the screenshot the labels are angled and are far too close together.

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RcBa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RcBa.png)

```
  private baseChartSpec: Record<string, any> = {
    $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json',
    width: 'container',
    height: 'container',
    view: { strokeOpacity: 0 },
    config: {
      axis: {
        ticks: false,
        titlePadding: 8,
        labelFontSize: 12,
        titleFontSize: 12,
        titleFont: 'Roboto',
        labelFont: 'Roboto',
        labelOverlap: true,
      },
      axisX: {
        labelAngle: 0,
        tickBand: DEFAULT_TICK_BAND_MODE,
        grid: DEFAULT_X_AXIS_GRID_VISIBLE,
        labelPadding: 7,
        labelOverlap: true,
      },
      axisY: {
        labelAngle: 0,
        grid: false,
        labelPadding: 7
      },
      scale: {
        bandPaddingInner: 0,
        bandPaddingOuter: 0
      },
      legend: {
        symbolType: 'circle',
        orient: 'bottom',
        title: null,
        labelFontSize: DEFAULT_LEGEND_LABEL_SIZE,
        labelFont: 'Roboto',
        symbolSize: DEFAULT_LEGEND_ICON_SIZE
      },
      bar: {
        color: VISUALIZATION_COLORS[0]
      },
      line: {
        color: VISUALIZATION_COLORS[1]
      }
    },
    encoding: {
      color: {
        field: DEFAULT_GROUP_FIELD_NAME,
        sort: null,
        scale: { range: [VISUALIZATION_COLORS[0], VISUALIZATION_COLORS[1], VISUALIZATION_COLORS[2]] }
      }
    },
    layer: [
      {
        // Do not change the order of these params.
        params: [
          {
            name: 'highlight',
            select: { type: 'point', on: 'mouseover' }
          },
          {
            name: 'select',
            select: { type: 'point', toggle: 'true' }
          }
        ],
        data: { name: 'barData' },
        mark: {
          type: 'bar',
          width: DEFAULT_BAR_BAND_MIN_WIDTH,
          align: 'center',
          stroke: 'black',
          cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        encoding: {
          x: {
            title: '',
            field: DEFAULT_X_FIELD_NAME,
            type: DEFAULT_BAR_X_FIELD_TYPE,
            axis: {
              format: '',
              formatType: '',
              labelOverlap: true,
            }
          },
          y: {
            title: '',
            field: DEFAULT_Y_FIELD_NAME,
            type: DEFAULT_BAR_Y_FIELD_TYPE
          },
          strokeWidth: {
            condition: [
              {
                param: 'highlight',
                empty: false,
                value: 1
              }
            ],
            value: 0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        data: { name: 'lineData' },
        mark: { type: 'line', interpolate: 'step' },
        encoding: {
          x: {
            field: DEFAULT_X_FIELD_NAME,
            type: DEFAULT_LINE_X_FIELD_TYPE,
            axis: {
              format: '',
              formatType: '',
              labelOverlap: true,
            }
          },
          y: {
            field: DEFAULT_Y_FIELD_NAME,
            type: DEFAULT_LINE_Y_FIELD_TYPE
          }
        }
      },
      {
        data: { name: 'ruleData' },
        encoding: {
          y: { field: DEFAULT_Y_FIELD_NAME, type: DEFAULT_RULE_Y_FIELD_TYPE, aggregate: 'sum' }
        },
        layer: [
          {
            mark: 'rule'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

```
<chart-line-bar
   id="bar-chart"
   ref="barChartRef"
   :data="data"
   x-axis-title=""
   is-x-axis-date="true"
   x-field-name="displayDate"
   x-axis-grid-visible="true"
   x-axis-label-angle="-45"
   :y-axis-title="$t('bids.numberOfAgents')"
   :tooltip="tooltipOptions()"
   group-name-field="group"
   legend-font-size="12"
   ignore-sort="true"
   line-point="true"
   bar-selection="false"
   bar-border="false"
   legend-icon-size="12"
   label-overlap="true"
   hide-tooltips-on-chart-click="false"
/>
```

Tried using labelOverlap, but outcome is not as expected (nothing has happened, no labels are being skipped over).

Comment: Can you post a full spec to debug?

Comment: @DavideBacci edited my posted with the whole schema and the vue component in the template. As you can see I've tried putting labelOverlap under `axis` and 'axisX', but neither have had an impact.

Comment: I'm not a React guy but I can see the spec. Do you have some sample data too?

Comment: The best way to solve this is create a version that recreates the issue in the online Vega editor. Then you can identify whether the issue is in Vega, Vega-Lite or React. At the moment, there is not enough info to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I created a simple label expression to only show if the minutes = 00. In future, if you need support from the community please provide a sample spec with test data and format with "" around all json elements.

```
"labelExpr": "datum.value[3] == '0' && datum.value[4] == '0' ? datum.value : ''"
```

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"time": "00:00", "value": 0.6773080696},
      {"time": "00:15", "value": 0.1956384448},
      {"time": "00:30", "value": 0.1612427676},
      {"time": "00:45", "value": 0.8207645699},
      {"time": "01:00", "value": 0.2980795796},
      {"time": "01:15", "value": 0.7365633882},
      {"time": "01:30", "value": 0.8999447393},
      {"time": "01:45", "value": 0.3499398829},
      {"time": "02:00", "value": 0.4794635699},
      {"time": "02:15", "value": 0.1956384448},
      {"time": "02:30", "value": 0.1612427676},
      {"time": "02:45", "value": 0.8207645699},
      {"time": "03:00", "value": 0.2980795796},
      {"time": "03:15", "value": 0.7365633882},
      {"time": "03:30", "value": 0.8999447393},
      {"time": "03:45", "value": 0.3499398829},
      {"time": "04:00", "value": 0.4794635699},
      {"time": "04:15", "value": 0.1956384448},
      {"time": "04:30", "value": 0.1612427676},
      {"time": "04:45", "value": 0.8207645699},
      {"time": "05:00", "value": 0.2980795796},
      {"time": "05:15", "value": 0.7365633882},
      {"time": "05:30", "value": 0.8999447393},
      {"time": "05:45", "value": 0.3499398829},
      {"time": "06:00", "value": 0.4794635699},
      {"time": "06:15", "value": 0.1956384448},
      {"time": "06:30", "value": 0.1612427676},
      {"time": "06:45", "value": 0.8207645699},
      {"time": "07:00", "value": 0.2980795796},
      {"time": "07:15", "value": 0.7365633882},
      {"time": "07:30", "value": 0.8999447393},
      {"time": "07:45", "value": 0.3499398829},
      {"time": "08:00", "value": 0.4794635699}
    ]
  },
  "width": 600,
  "height": 400,
  "view": {"strokeOpacity": 0},
  "config": {
    "axis": {
      "ticks": true,
      "titlePadding": 8,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "titleFontSize": 12,
      "titleFont": "Roboto",
      "labelFont": "Roboto",
      "labelOverlap": true
    },
    "axisX": {"labelAngle": 0, "labelPadding": 7, "labelOverlap": true},
    "axisY": {"labelAngle": 0, "grid": false, "labelPadding": 7},
    "scale": {"bandPaddingInner": 0, "bandPaddingOuter": 0},
    "legend": {
      "symbolType": "circle",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "title": null,
      "labelFontSize": 10,
      "labelFont": "Roboto",
      "symbolSize": 10
    },
    "bar": {"color": "blue"},
    "line": {"color": "blue"}
  },
  "encoding": {},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "interpolate": "step-after",
        "align": "center",
        "stroke": "black",
        "cursor": "pointer"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "title": "",
          "field": "time",
          "axis": {
            "labelExpr": "datum.value[3] == '0' && datum.value[4] == '0' ? datum.value : ''"
          }
        },
        "y": {"title": "", "field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "point", "stroke": "black", "cursor": "pointer"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "title": "",
          "field": "time",
          "axis": {
            "labelExpr": "datum.value[3] == '0' && datum.value[4] == '0' ? datum.value : ''"
          }
        },
        "y": {"title": "", "field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]